# DevExtreme FilterBuilder display criteria within dialog

Tags: devextreme

Wondering if anyone knows how to approach displaying the net result of a grid spawned filter builder within the dialog as it's being changed?

[image: filter builder]

Thinking of maybe grafting an element into the dialog's DOM using jquery and then updating its value during the valueChanged event by accessing the
getFilterExpression method.  Is this a sound approach or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving it using the approach I mentioned above plus a little inspiration from this [support ticket](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t827587/datagrid-how-to-get-parsed-text-from-the-filter-builder-filter-panel) to access a friendly formatted version of the filter.

```js
function setGridPopupFilterExpression(grid, filter) {
    if (filter == null) {
        $('#popupFilterExpressionValue').text('None');
    } else {
        const operations = grid.getController('filterSync').getCustomFilterOperations();
        grid.getView('filterPanelView').getFilterText(filter, operations).then(function(result) {  
             $('#popupFilterExpressionValue').text(result);
        });
    }
}

// create grid
const grid = gridContainer.dxDataGrid({
    filterPanel: { visible: true },
    headerFilter: { visible: true },
    filterBuilderPopup: {
        wrapperAttr: { id: 'popupFilter' },
        onShowing: function (e) {
            $('#popupFilter').find('.dx-popup-content').prepend("<div class='popupFilterExpression'><span class='popupFilterExpressionLabel'>Expression:</span> <span id='popupFilterExpressionValue'>None</span></div>");
        }
    },
    filterBuilder: {
        onInitialized: function (e) {
            setGridPopupFilterExpression(grid, e.component.getFilterExpression());
        },
        onValueChanged: function (e) {
            setGridPopupFilterExpression(grid, e.component.getFilterExpression());
        }
    }
}
```